# Add custom texture to an extruded polygon face in Google Earth Pro

Tags: google-earth

I am trying to add a custom texture (.png or .jpeg) to the face of an extruded polygon (in this case a retaining wall) in Google Earth Pro.

I have done this easily with a point file and .png with transparent background, but can't seem to get a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a texture to a 3D polygon is not possible directly in KML... like if the polygon is defined as a KML geometry and extruded to some altitude.  For those, you can specify line and fill colors for polygons, but not fill textures/images.

One way to do this is to use a 3D Model instead, which is basically a Collada file loaded via KML.  Note that this currently only works in Earth Pro (desktop) and not in Earth for web or mobile.  You can find more info in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/models